# Bad display textbox of theme my login on firefox (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, plugins

I am having a problem with my site that I am building on wordpress. Even though everything works fine, I realized that the text box of the plugin THEME MY LOGIN displays the letters entered cut (a part of them only is displayed). I am attaching a photo so you can see what I am talking about. The problem only appears with this particular plug in and only on firefox. on chrome, iphone, android phone browser (default browser) it seems ok (android firefox has errors too). Can anyone provide a slution? I have no idea of php or css so please if you are going to give any part of code, keep that in mind (although I can understand code).
[image]

Comment: Unluckly It is hard to give you a solution without looking at the code. If you use your f12 developer toolbar you can inspect this input field. This will allow you to read the html and the css of that input field, so that you can share the code. I am not allowed to give you any help without the code.

Comment: I didn;t write any code for this plugin. If you are asking for the code of the site, it can be found at gcu.gr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme and that plugin have different values for 'box-sizing' CSS property, so when theme sets height to 16px it's calculated with padding and border which effectively makes for only 2px height.

You can set this CSS to correct plugin's behavior:

```
.tml * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: ok.but where should I put this code? (I am really asking this questin...I have no understand of css and where in the wordpress to put the code)

Comment: It depends on your theme, some themes have a Custom CSS field in their options where you could enter this CSS, if there is no such field you will have to enter it in a CSS file on your server.

Answer (score 1):

I inspected the website and the problem I found is pretty simple. 
The input field has a height of few pixels, I edited that height and it looks fine as you can see from the screenshot.

You can edit the input[type="text"] css in the file style.css row 434 as you want.

```
input[type="text"] {
 height: 26px;
}
```

Maybe this is not the solution you are searching for?
Then please comment and explain me..
Thanks
Fabrizio

[image]

Comment: I found nothing that matches the code input[type="text"] and has after it some kind of height (except the login page which was fine as it was (i didnt use theme my login plugin for the login))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure height and line-height are set correctly on all inputs. This is probably just a CSS problem.